# Modify php for 'read more' text to link to a specific WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress, variable-assignment

I am trying to modify the 'Read More' in a WordPress plugin to link to a specific page instead of the default equivalent of a post. In this case it is part of a testimonials plugin.

I have located instructions to add the following code to the end of the theme `functions.php` file and modify the `$more_text` variable, but I am not sure where the page id or url should be added and if it should replace any of the existing snippet. This is the code—

```
function hg_testimonial_rotator_the_excerpt( $html, $limit )
{
    $more_text = '... <a class="read-more"    href="'.get_permalink(get_the_ID()).'">Read the Rest...</a>';
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit, $more_text);
}
add_filter('testimonial_rotator_the_excerpt',    'hg_testimonial_rotator_the_excerpt', 10, 2);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the a href you can put your new link.

```
$more_text = '... <a class="read-more" href="here goes your new link">Read the Rest...</a>';
```

You can add a static link for example:

```
$more_text = '... <a class="read-more" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">Read the Rest...</a>';
```

Or you can generate a link like in your example.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.